# Make JTree from database

Tags: java, jtree

i have a database with two columns `parent` and `child`
and it have following data

```
parent   |   child 
===================
sara     |   danny
sara     |   benny
dia      |   tom
aria     |   jenny
aria     |   sunny
```

and i want to display it in `JTree` like this

```
-parent
  *sara
      +danny
      +benny
  *dia
      +tom
  *aria
      +jenny
      +sunny
```

from `ResultSet` i am getting each row.. but how to create `DefaultMutableTreeNode` only once and add child in single `while` loop? how to check if `node` is already made?

Comment: Can you show us what you already tried?

Comment: One way would be to query the database several times.  First, get all the root parents.  Then, for each root parent, get all the children.  Repeat until every child as parent query returns no rows.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Thankyou! you gave me a Kick start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution, it could be a wrong approach, But it worked. So i called `newRow` function for each row.

```
TreeMap group = new TreeMap();

void newRow(String Parent,String Child) {

if(group.containsKey(Parent)) {

    //if Parent already in group return Arraylist of child
    ArrayList<String> al = (ArrayList<String>) group.get(Parent);

    //Add new Child to ArrayList
    al.add(Child);
}
else {
    ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<>();
    al.add(Child);

    //if new Parent add parent and its Child ArrayList
    group.put(groupname,al);
}

}
```

When i iterated through `TreeMap group` this was the outPut and i used it to make JTree

```
sara : [danny , benny]
dia : [tom]
aria : [jenny, sunny]
```